# Change the background color of font-awesome circle icon

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm using 2 icons from font-awesome, A `+` in front and a circle in the back.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qvxcmwse/10)

I'm trying to change the background color of the circle, But it's not working.

Here is the code:

```css
.fa-plus{
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.image{
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%
}

.wrapper span{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 15%;
  width: 15%;
  height: 15%;
  z-index: 2;
}

#input{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="file" id="input" name="image" accept="image/*">
  <img class="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTRT2XK4W0i7icS84Yq5VHpwZ9anmDXoOFQZX0anUhWxcpL5du_">
  <span class="fa-stack" aria-hidden="true">
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-plus fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

I'm using the circle to give the `+` icon a circular background color, I tried to add the `+` icon only and give it `padding`, But didn't work too:

```css
.fa-plus{
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.image{
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%
}

.wrapper span{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 15%;
  width: 15%;
  height: 15%;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 10%;
}

#input{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="file" id="input" name="image" accept="image/*">
  <img class="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTRT2XK4W0i7icS84Yq5VHpwZ9anmDXoOFQZX0anUhWxcpL5du_">
  <span class="fa-stack" aria-hidden="true">
    <i class="fa fa-plus fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Which colour do you need to change. In your code I can change the circular colour behind the `+` using the `.fa-plus` `background-color` CSS.

Comment: @Chris, the circle background

Comment: The red one or the black one?

Comment: @Swellar, I added the red one, I want to change the black to red

Answer (score 1):

Add this property in CSS.

```
i.fa.fa-circle.fa-stack-2x{
color:green;
}
```

If you want to change the plus background from red to green(I haven't included in the code snippet)

```
i.fa.fa-plus.fa-stack-1x.fa-inverse {
background: green;
}
```

```css
.fa-plus{
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
i.fa.fa-circle.fa-stack-2x{
color:green;
}
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.image{
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%
}

.wrapper span{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 15%;
  width: 15%;
  height: 15%;
  z-index: 2;
}

#input{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="file" id="input" name="image" accept="image/*">
  <img class="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTRT2XK4W0i7icS84Yq5VHpwZ9anmDXoOFQZX0anUhWxcpL5du_">
  <span class="fa-stack" aria-hidden="true">
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-plus fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: So the black wasn't a background, But a color!

Comment: It's changed to red now, But the `+` is not in the middle of the circle http://jsfiddle.net/qvxcmwse/58/

Answer (score 0):

Try this HTML and CSS. I removed the entire black circle and replaced it with the CSS clip-path property as a background for the plus-sign (It works very well for big-to-medium screens, but sadly it doesn't for small-to-extra-small screens, so you have to set a min-width property for the .wrapper span, I guess):

```css
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.image{
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%
}

.wrapper span{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 15%;
  width: 15%;
  height: 15%;
  z-index: 2;
}

#input{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
}
.fa-plus{
  background:black;
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(38% at 50% 50%);
  clip-path: circle(38% at 50% 50%);
}
```

```html
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="file" id="input" name="image" accept="image/*">
  <img class="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTRT2XK4W0i7icS84Yq5VHpwZ9anmDXoOFQZX0anUhWxcpL5du_">
  <span class="fa-stack" aria-hidden="true">
    <i class="fa fa-plus fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your  .wrapper span  CSS properties to below:

```
.wrapper span {

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 15%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```